# What is the first parameter of Router.route in Meteor's iron router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Reading the `Discover Meteor` book (and many blogs) the following syntax is used:

```
Router.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    // ...
});
```

But the iron router github quick guide uses:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    // ...
});
```

And I have even seen:

```
Router.route({
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    // ...
});
```

Which is considered correct? How are number 1 and 2 separated from one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "correct" syntax as they are all accepted by `iron:router`, however, number 2 is arguably most commonly found because it's the one used in the guide after all.

Routing is all about URLs so I consider that defining a route by first indicating its path makes sense.

`iron:router` can tell the difference between syntax 1 and 2 simply because the options object passed as second argument will likely contain `path` or `name` as properties, and it will assume that the first argument was the other one. If there's no `name` or `path` properties specified, it will assume the first argument is a path.